# The Chozeh Mi'Lublin prioritizing dveikus over kriyas shema

Tags: sources-mekorot, chasidut-hasidism, shema, quotations

I heard someone quote from the Chozeh (parshas Pinchas) that if one is in a state of dveikus with Hashem and zman kriyas shemah is arriving (or passing?) the yetzer harah says to stop for kriyas shemah and the yetzer hatov says to continue with your state of dveikus. (This was quoted in contrast to the Nefesh HaChaim's position).

Can someone confirm that the Chozeh held such an idea and source it?

Comment: I can't imagine he would say such a ridiculous thing. Any claim otherwise is clearly a forgery.

Comment: I agree that it very well may be apocryphal. But aren't some chassidim known for davening later that the required times? If so maybe this was something said at one point in support of that practice.

Comment: If the story is true, it sounds like he was presenting a scenario where someone could serve HaShem with his "*yetzer hara*" by interrupting his rapture to recite  *k'riyas sh'ma* on time (along the lines of [*B'rachos* 54a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=54&format=text), בכל לבבך בשני יצריך ביצר טוב וביצר הרע). Ideally, though, קריאת שמע and דביקות should go hand in hand.

Comment: I think that [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3624&st=&pgnum=128) is the passage you're referring to.

Answer (score 2):

From [this Hebrew Wikipedia article](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%91%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%94#.D7.97.D7.A1.D7.99.D7.93.D7.95.D7.AA_.D7.95.D7.9E.D7.AA.D7.A0.D7.92.D7.93.D7.99.D7.9D)

> תלמידו החוזה מלובלין ניסה לתרץ את אי הקפדת החסידים בזמני קריאת שמע
>   ותפילה, בחשיבות הכוונה ורצונו של הקב"ה בליבו של האדם, וכתב כי לפעמים
>   כאשר הצדיק שוקל כי עתה רצון הבורא שיעסוק בדבר שיגרום נחת רוח לבורא
>   ית"ש, הוא עובר לפעמים על זמן קריאת שמע ותפילה1].

Quoted from [זכרון זאת פרשת פינחס](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=3624&hilite=b4bcea4c-4bf0-41aa-acab-f8edf849760d&st=%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%90%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%9E%D7%A2&pgnum=128)